# how to iterate over each element in two columns of different length

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-maps-api-3, google-distancematrix-api

I have two columns in a CSV file, and I want to make a loop with Python, so I can match each element from one list to the other. I'm doing it to create a file with multiple itineraries from the GoogleMaps API. So what I actually want to do is map distances from a list of origins to a list of destinations, for each element in both lists.

It's something like this:

```
origins = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
destinations = ['E', 'F', 'G']
```

And I want an output like this:

```
Distances_from = ['aE', 'aF', 'aG', 'bE', 'bF', 'bG', 'cE', 'cF', 'cG', 'dE', 'dF', 'dG']
```

My code is:

```
destination_index=0 #city code
destination_coordinates=10
origin_index=12
origin_coordinates=13

reader=csv.reader(municipalities)
writer=csv.writer(output)

try:
    for row in list(reader)[1:]:
         destination_c=row[destination_coordinates]
         origin_c=row[origin_coordinates]

         destination_name=row[destination_index]
         origin_name=row[origin_index]

     for destination_coordinates, origin_coordinates in zip(destination_c, origin_c):
         distances = gmaps.distance_matrix(origin_c, destination_c) 

         if distances['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['status'] == "OK": 
            writer.writerow((destination_name,origin_name,
                                 distances['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['value'], 
                                 distances['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration']['value']))          
         else:
            writer.writerow((destination_name,origin_name,
                             ".", 
                             "."))         
finally:
    municipalities.close()
    output.close()
```

Comment: what exactly are `a, b, ..., E, F, G`? Strings? If so, use some quotes. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Add your code and the explanation of what all those are in the question body by hitting on the `edit` link.

Comment: thanks, I uploaded my code, can you try and see what I can do to fix it?

Comment: What do you expect this code to do and what is it outputting at the moment? Could you post a link to a csv. files that give you trouble?

Answer (score 0):

A list comprehension will do:

```
origins=['a','b','c','d']
destinations=['E','F','G']

Distances_from = ["{}{}".format(x,y) for x in origins for y in destinations]
print(Distances_from)
# ['aE', 'aF', 'aG', 'bE', 'bF', 'bG', 'cE', 'cF', 'cG', 'dE', 'dF', 'dG']
```

Obviously, you need to change what you want to do (probably not `"{}{}".format(x,y)`).

Comment: thanks, I uploaded my code, can you try and see what I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Is it as simple as nested for loop, you are searching for:

```
for origin in origins:
    for destination in destinations:
        distance(origin, destination)
        ...
```

To write it in a more succinct manner you could do:

```
from functools import product
for origin, destination in product(origins, destinations):
    distance(origin, destination)
```

Or use list comprehension:

```
distances = [distance(origin, destination) 
                      for origin in origins 
                      for destination in destinations]
```

Comment: thanks, I uploaded my code, can you try and see what I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I think i've almost solved it, I keep having some problems but I thinks it's because of the Google API rather than the code.
Here is the code I used.

@JanHak

```
dest_f=open(os.path.join(dir,'Colombian_Municipalities.csv'),'r')
orig_f=open(os.path.join(dir,'Origins.csv'),'r')
output_f=open(os.path.join(dir,'Distances_to_Bogota.csv'),'w')

# Constants
dest_code_index=0 # detination city code
dest_coord_index=10 # Coordinates from all municipalities in Colombia
orig_code_index=0 #
orig_coord_index=1 # Coordinates from markets and seaports



dest_reader=csv.reader(dest_f)
orig_reader=csv.reader(orig_f)
output_writer=csv.writer(output_f)
output_header=['Origin','Destination','Distance (meters)','Duration (seconds)']
output_writer.writerow(output_header)


orig_reader_list=list(orig_reader)
dest_reader_list=list(dest_reader)        


try:

for dest_row in dest_reader_list[1:]:

    dest_code=dest_row[dest_code_index]
    dest_coord=dest_row[dest_coord_index]


    for orig_row in orig_reader_list[1:]:

        orig_code=orig_row[orig_code_index]
        orig_coord=orig_row[orig_coord_index]

        print(orig_code,dest_code)

        distances=gmaps.distance_matrix(orig_coord, dest_coord) 

        if distances['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['status']=="OK": 
            output_writer.writerow((dest_code,orig_code,
                                 distances['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['value'], 
                                 distances['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration']['value']))             
        else:
            output_writer.writerow((dest_code,orig_code,
                             ".", 
                             "."))         

finally:
dest_f.close()
orig_f.close()
output_f.close()
```